# Why is my CUDA implementation equally fast as my CPU implementation

Tags: c++, cuda, nvidia, convolution

I created some code to do a 2D convlution on a 1300x1300 grayscale image and a 15x15 kernel, in standard C++ and in CUDA. Both versions:

CPU:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

#define N 1300
#define K 15
#define K2 ((K - 1) / 2)


template<int mx, int my>
inline int index(int x, int y)
{
  return x*my + y;
}

int main() {
  double *image  = new double[N * N];
  double *kernel = new double[K * K];
  double *result = new double[N * N];
  
  for (int x=0; x<N; ++x)
  for (int y=0; y<N; ++y)
  {
    double r = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<K; ++i)
    for(int j=0; j<K; ++j)
    {
      if (x + i - K2 >= 0 and
          x + i - K2 < N  and
          y + j - K2 >= 0 and
          y + j - K2 < N)
      {
        r +=  kernel[index<K,K>(i,j)] * image[index<N,N>(x+i-K2, y+j-K2)];
      }
    }
    result[index<N,N>(x, y)] = r;
  }
  
  delete[] image;
  delete[] kernel;
  delete[] result;
}
```

GPU:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

// ignore, just for error handling
struct ErrorHandler {
  int d_line;
  char const *d_file;
  ErrorHandler(int line, char const *file) : d_line(line), d_file(file) {};
};

#define EH ErrorHandler(__LINE__, __FILE__)

ErrorHandler operator<<(ErrorHandler eh, cudaError_t err)
{
  if (err != cudaSuccess)
  {
    std::cerr << cudaGetErrorString( err ) << " in " << eh.d_file << " at line " << eh.d_line << '\n';
    throw std::exception();
  }
  return eh;
}
// end.

#define N 1300
#define K 15
#define K2 ((K - 1) / 2)


template<int mx, int my>
__device__ inline int index(int x, int y)
{
  return x*my + y;
}

__global__ void kernelkernel(double *image, double *kernel, double *result)
{
  int x = blockIdx.x;
  int y = blockIdx.y; // becomes: int y = threadIdx.x;
  
  double r = 0;
  for(int i=0; i<K; ++i)
  for(int j=0; j<K; ++j)
  {
    if (x + i - K2 >= 0 and
        x + i - K2 < N  and
        y + j - K2 >= 0 and
        y + j - K2 < N)
    {
      r +=  kernel[index<K,K>(i,j)] * image[index<N,N>(x+i-K2, y+j-K2)];
    }
  }
  result[index<N,N>(x, y)] = r;
}

int main() {
  double *image      = new double[N * N];
  double *kernel    = new double[K * K];
  double *result      = new double[N * N];
  
  double *image_cuda;
  double *kernel_cuda;
  double *result_cuda;
  EH << cudaMalloc((void **) &image_cuda,  N*N*sizeof(double));
  EH << cudaMalloc((void **) &kernel_cuda, K*K*sizeof(double));
  EH << cudaMalloc((void **) &result_cuda, N*N*sizeof(double));
  
  EH << cudaMemcpy(image_cuda,     image,     N*N*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  EH << cudaMemcpy(kernel_cuda,    kernel,    K*K*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  
  dim3 grid   ( N, N );
  kernelkernel<<<grid, 1>>>(image_cuda, kernel_cuda, result_cuda);
  // replace previous 2 statements with: 
  // kernelkernel<<<N, N>>>(image_cuda, kernel_cuda, result_cuda);
  EH << cudaMemcpy(result, result_cuda, N*N*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

  cudaFree( image_cuda );
  cudaFree( kernel_cuda );
  cudaFree( result_cuda );
  
  delete[] image;
  delete[] kernel;
  delete[] result;
}
```

I would expect the cuda code to be a lot faster, however:

```
$ nvprof ./gpuversion
==17806== NVPROF is profiling process 17806, command: ./gpuversion
==17806== Profiling application: ./gpuversion
==17806== Profiling result:
Time(%)      Time     Calls       Avg       Min       Max  Name
99.89%  3.83149s         1  3.83149s  3.83149s  3.83149s  kernelkernel(double*, double*, double*)
  0.07%  2.6420ms         1  2.6420ms  2.6420ms  2.6420ms  [CUDA memcpy DtoH]
  0.04%  1.5111ms         2  755.54us     736ns  1.5103ms  [CUDA memcpy HtoD]
```

And:

```
$ time ./cpuversion
real    0m3.382s
user    0m3.371s
sys     0m0.012s
```

Their difference is statistically insignificant. The CUDA-kernel takes approximately 3-4 seconds, why isn't it a lot faster? Is my code run in parallel?

PS: I'm new to CUDA, so I could be missing something trivial.

### SOLUTION

What I found out, is that CUDA does not let you access memory willy-nilly from blocks. I guess the general strategy of CUDA programming is:

- allocate and copy memory from RAM to cuda using cudaMalloc and cudaMemCpy
- divide the workload among blocks and threads in such a way that the memory accessed by different blocks doesn't overlap much.
- If there is overlap between the memory used by blocks, start each block by copying the memory inside a **shared** array. Notice that:

  - the size of this array must be known compile time
  - it's size is limited
  - this memory is shared by each thread in ONE block, so __shared double foo[10] allocates 10 doubles for each BLOCK.
- copy the memory needed by one block to the **shared** variables inside the kernel. Of course, you use the different threads to do this 'efficiently'
- sync the threads, such that all data is there before it is used.
- process the data, and write the result. it to the output array of the kernel
- synch again, I'm not sure why, but everyone on the internet is doing it :S
- copy the GPU memory back to RAM
- clean up the GPU memory.

This gives the following code. It is mex-code, for Matlab for the structural similarity, which also works via a sliding kernel, but over 2 images and with a different aggregate than the dot-product.

```
// author: Herbert Kruitbosch, CC: be nice, include my name in documentation/papers/publications when used
#include <matrix.h>
#include <mex.h>

#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

static void HandleError(
  cudaError_t err,
  const char *file,
  int line )
{
  if (err != cudaSuccess)
  {
    printf( "%s in %s at line %d\n", cudaGetErrorString( err ), file, line );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
  }
}

#define HANDLE_ERROR( err ) (HandleError( err, __FILE__, __LINE__ ))
#define TILE_WIDTH 31

__device__ inline double sim(double v0, double v1, double c)
{
  return (c + 2*v0*v1) / (c + v1*v1 + v0*v0);
}

__device__ inline int index(int rows, int cols, int row, int col)
{
  return row + col*rows;
}

__global__ void ssimkernel(double *test, double *reference, const double * __restrict__ kernel, double *ssim, int k, int rows, int cols, int tile_batches_needed)
{
  int radius = k / 2;
  int block_width = TILE_WIDTH - k + 1;
  __shared__ double tile_test     [TILE_WIDTH][TILE_WIDTH];
  __shared__ double tile_reference[TILE_WIDTH][TILE_WIDTH];
  
  
  
  for(int offset=0; offset < tile_batches_needed; ++offset)
  {
    int dest = block_width*block_width*offset + threadIdx.y * block_width + threadIdx.x;
    int destRow = dest / TILE_WIDTH;
    int destCol = dest % TILE_WIDTH;
    int srcRow = blockIdx.y * block_width + destRow - radius;
    int srcCol = blockIdx.x * block_width + destCol - radius;
    int src  = srcCol * rows + srcRow;
    if (destRow < TILE_WIDTH)
    {
      if (srcRow >= 0 and srcRow < rows and
          srcCol >= 0 and srcCol < cols)
      {
        tile_test     [destRow][destCol] = test     [src];
        tile_reference[destRow][destCol] = reference[src];
      }
      else
      {
        tile_test     [destRow][destCol] = 0;
        tile_reference[destRow][destCol] = 0;
      }
    }
  }
  __syncthreads();
  
  double mean_test = 0;
  double mean_reference = 0;
  for(int i=0; i<k; ++i)
  for(int j=0; j<k; ++j)
  {
    double w = kernel[i * k + j];
    mean_test      +=  w * tile_test     [threadIdx.y+i][threadIdx.x+j];
    mean_reference +=  w * tile_reference[threadIdx.y+i][threadIdx.x+j];
  }
  
  double var_test = 0;
  double var_reference = 0;
  double correlation = 0;
  for(int i=0; i<k; ++i)
  for(int j=0; j<k; ++j)
  {
    double w = kernel[i * k + j];
    double a = (tile_test     [threadIdx.y+i][threadIdx.x+j] - mean_test     );
    double b = (tile_reference[threadIdx.y+i][threadIdx.x+j] - mean_reference);
    var_test      += w * a * a;
    var_reference += w * b * b;
    correlation   += w * a * b;
  }
  
  int destRow = blockIdx.y * block_width + threadIdx.y;
  int destCol = blockIdx.x * block_width + threadIdx.x;
  if (destRow < rows and destCol < cols)
    ssim[destCol * rows + destRow] = sim(mean_test, mean_reference, 0.01) * (0.03 + 2*correlation) / (0.03 + var_test + var_reference);
  
  __syncthreads();
}


template<typename T>
inline T sim(T v0, T v1, T c)
{
  return (c + 2*v0*v1) / (c + v1*v1 + v0*v0);
}

inline int upperdiv(int a, int b) {
  return (a + b - 1) / b;
}

void mexFunction(int nargout, mxArray *argout[], int nargin, const mxArray *argin[])
{
  mwSize rows = mxGetDimensions(argin[0])[0];
  mwSize cols = mxGetDimensions(argin[0])[1];
  mwSize k    = mxGetDimensions(argin[2])[0];
  mwSize channels = mxGetNumberOfDimensions(argin[0]) <= 2 ? 1 : mxGetDimensions(argin[0])[2];
  int dims[] = {rows, cols, channels};
  argout[0] = mxCreateNumericArray(3, dims, mxDOUBLE_CLASS, mxREAL);
  
  double *test      = (double *)mxGetData(argin[0]);
  double *reference = (double *)mxGetData(argin[1]);
  double *gaussian  = (double *)mxGetData(argin[2]);
  double *ssim      = (double *)mxGetData(argout[0]);
  
  double *test_cuda;
  double *reference_cuda;
  double *gaussian_cuda;
  double *ssim_cuda;
  HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMalloc((void **) &test_cuda,      rows*cols*sizeof(double)) );
  HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMalloc((void **) &reference_cuda, rows*cols*sizeof(double)) );
  HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMalloc((void **) &gaussian_cuda,  k*k*sizeof(double)) );
  HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMalloc((void **) &ssim_cuda,      rows*cols*sizeof(double)) );
  HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMemcpy(gaussian_cuda,  gaussian,  k*k*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice) );
  
  int block_width = TILE_WIDTH - k + 1;
  int tile_batches_needed = upperdiv(TILE_WIDTH*TILE_WIDTH, block_width*block_width);
  
  for(int c=0; c<channels; ++c)
  {
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMemcpy(test_cuda,      test      + rows*cols*c, rows*cols*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice) );
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMemcpy(reference_cuda, reference + rows*cols*c, rows*cols*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice) );
    dim3 dimGrid(upperdiv(cols, block_width), upperdiv(rows, block_width), 1);
    dim3 dimBlock(block_width, block_width, 1);
    
    ssimkernel<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(test_cuda, reference_cuda, gaussian_cuda, ssim_cuda, k, rows, cols, tile_batches_needed);
    
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMemcpy(ssim + rows*cols*c, ssim_cuda, rows*cols*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost) );
  }
  cudaFree( test_cuda );
  cudaFree( reference_cuda );
  cudaFree( gaussian_cuda );
  cudaFree( ssim_cuda );
}
```

Comment: You are running one thread per block. That wastes about 96% of the available GPU instruction throughput. It should be no surprise the performance is suboptimal....

Comment: Your edited profile data shows no kernel execution time. Are you should you haven't broken something else?

Comment: Yes, i would worry about @talonmies' observation. Have you validated the output of your kernel? I would also put an error check just after launching the kernel; e.g. `EH << cudaGetLastError();`. I'm not sure if `cudaMemcpy` will warn you if something fishy happened.

Comment: @Hurkyl: I did validate, unfortunately I couldn't notice the difference because (so I think) the valid result was already calculated and kept in memory, but not overwritten. Thank you for your comment, it is indeed correct that the solution mentioned above does not work. Sincere apologies for this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
kernelkernel<<<grid, 1>>>
```

This is a significant issue; threads on nVidia GPUs work in warps of 32 threads. However, you've only assigned a single thread to each block, which means 31 of those threads will sit idle while a single thread does work. And usually, for kernels where you have the flexibility, you'll usually want several warps per block rather than just one.

You could get an immediate speedup by using N blocks and N threads per block, rather than using N^2 blocks.

Actually, N might be too big, since there's an upper limit on the number of threads per block. Although you could choose a suitable M so that that you use N/M threads per block, and N * M blocks.

In fact, you'll probably get the best results in this regard by picking some M (I'm guessing 256 will probably be near optimal) and launching with `L=ceiling(N*N/M)` blocks and M blocks per thread. Then each thread figures reconstructs an index in `[0, M*L)` based on its block and thread ID, and then those whose index is in `[0,N*N)` will proceed to split that index into an x and y coordinate and do work.

Comment: This seems very accurate, I updated code with comments to achieve this, but not with the fancy way of indexing, to optimize thread usage. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Accessing global memory in a kernel is costly, because of its latency. A global memory request (both reading and writing) takes hundreds of clock cycles to complete. You want to minimise the amount of times global memory is accessed, and access it in contiguous blocks.

If each piece of data is accessed exactly once, there's nothing to do about the latency, but that's seldom the case. And definitely not the case in your code, where the `kernel` array is accessed by all threads in the same pattern, and a lot of `image` is accessed by multiple threads as well.

The solution for that is to start the kernel by fetching the data from the high-latency *global memory* into the low-latency *shared memory.* Shared memory is a block of memory on the multiprocessor, and its latency is comparable to that of registers. So most simple kernels follow a structure like this:

1. Each thread fetches data from global memory to shared memory. You want to fetch data in contiguous sequences if possible, as global memory is accessed through transactions. If there's not enough data for all threads to fetch, leave some of them idle.
2. Threads operate on the data in shared memory.
3. Data is written from shared memory back to global memory in the same pattern as it was fetched in step 1.

Shared memory is shared by all threads within a thread block. Which leads us to the second big issue in your code: you're not using thread blocks at all. Threads in one block run on one multiprocessor, share shared memory, can be synchronised with each other etc. You need to organise threads into blocks well to get the most out of them.

The grid of blocks is just a mechanism to be able to run more blocks at one invocation. All the goodies of parallel instruction execution and shared memory access are *within* a block. The grid of blocks is just "yeah, sorry, my data's so big a single block won't do, just run many of them."

You're doing the exact opposite: your blocks have one thread each, which means that in each step, only one thread from each warp runs on the multiprocessor (based on your device's compute capability and the number of warp schedulers available, this means something like 2–4 threads on one multiprocessor at most).

You'll have to re-structure your threads to mirror the data access patterns, and prefetch data into shared memory. This will give you the performance boost you expect.

---

The above is just a short summary. Refer to the CUDA programming guide for details on block organisation, shared memory, and global memory transactions.

Comment: Could the person who downvoted this, give feedback on why this is inaccurate or suboptimal information? This seems relevant.

Comment: This is nitpicking a bit, but multiple blocks can run at the same time, in a time-sliced fashion. (and it can sometimes be important to have this happen, as threads from one block can run when all of the threads of another block are blocked for various reasons)

Comment: @Hurkyl Clarified. My point was that two blocks cannot run on the same multiprocessor in the same clock cycle.

Comment: @Angew - That is still incorrect. Instructions from warps from different blocks can be scheduled in the same clock cycle.

Comment: @void_ptr I wasn't aware of that. Does that mean some form of mixing warps in one tick? Can you point me to a reference where I could learn more?

Comment: @Angew - This, for example: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#compute-capability-3-0 Note how each SM has 4 warp schedulers. Warps from all blocks running on this SM are distributed between schedulers. Here is a higher level overview: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#hardware-implementation

Comment: @void_ptr OK, reworded again. Better?

Comment: @Angew - I think it's fine. One could argue that if pipelining is taken into account, that increases the number of threads running in parallel even further. But as far as delivering the message that running one thread per block is bad for performance goes, the paragraph is clear, I believe.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using global memory in CUDA, all the data access will be synchronized in something like queue, and you'll receive almost linear solution, not parallel.
Also, transfering a large dataset from your RAM memory to GPU memory also takes a lot of time (the speed of bus is limited).
So, i think you have to somehow parallel your data across computation units in your GPU (part them into shared memory).
Check [this](http://www.shodor.org/media/content/petascale/materials/UPModules/matrixMultiplication/moduleDocument.pdf) to see solution of how to improve your GPU memory usage in the case that similar to yours.

Comment: I don't think the memory copy is actually a bottleneck, as indicated by nvprof, but the notion about storing things locally seems fair.